# Opening Shadowboxes on mouseenter using .attr()

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, shadowbox

I want to be able to hover over a shadowbox to open it and I have searched for a while, but I still do not entirely understand the concept of how to do it. Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="tapaintings">
            <tr>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting1"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting1.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting2"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting2.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting3"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting3.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting4.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting4"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting4.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting5.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting5"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting5.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
                <td><a id="shadowbox[paintings]" href="images/painting6.jpg" rel="shadowbox[paintings]" title="painting6"> <img src="images/thumbnails/t_painting6.jpg" alt="painting"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and my jquery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/painting1.jpg");
    });
});
```

I have just been trying to get the first image to enlarge at the moment, but I would like to be able to hover over any thumbnail and be able to open my shadowbox. As well I want to be able to continuously cycle through photos so that I can close the shadowbox i am on using mouseleave. I am a beginner at jQuery so I have been unable to grasp this concept so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a jquery plugin??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the $ in front of the jQuery object declarations. Also make sure you have the extension on your file (.jsp; .png; etc.).Try this (I haven't verified yet):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", images/painting1.jsp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok I added the cash symbols and .jpg to the end, but my shadowbox still won't open. I am also only using this source just for the moment until I can get the mouseenter function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this ?

```
$(function(){
    $('#tapaintings a').mouseenter(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a#' + id + ' img').animate({
            'height' : '80px',
            'width'  : '80px'
        });
    });
.........
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/8zZwN/)

Comment: I think you have roughly the idea of it, but when I tried to implement this code it did not work. Also is it possible to animate the photo's in accordance to the size I already have instead of choosing a height and width? The last thing I need to do is animate the photo on the right rather than have it enlarge right on top of the thumbnail.